# RewriteCond subdirectory is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to do RewriteRule for subdirectory and I could not do it.
This is the code:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
```

I use the following code with the above as well to remove the .php extension and add  a trailing slash at the end.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

I can access any page except index.php
I need someone to help me fix this issue so I can access the pages/files in the subdirectory.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly check if the php file exists before you add the .php extension. And remember that rewrite conditions *only* apply to the immediately following rule, so you need to duplicate them if they need to apply to multiple rules. Also, you want all your redirects to happen *before* any routing or rewrites:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php

# whatever subfolder rewrites you need can go here
```

Comment: When I use my code, I can access any page except index.php. Thank you